# Mapping the fields of two database tables

Tags: sql, database, abap, sap-data-dictionary

The scenario is that, I have 2 database tables A and B. The table B is an upgraded version of the table A. (ie It might possibly have different field names and some extra fields). I need to compare these 2 tables to inform the user about these extra fields and propose to him a mapping of the fields between the tables.

Currently I am thinking of comparing them using info like field name, data element and domain in that order.

Is there a standard way to do this? Thanks in advance.

---

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428271/sql-server-compare-columns-in-two-tables

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4827751/compare-two-columns-in-a-select

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard tool to do this - why would you want to do it this way anyway? The canonical way is to extend the original table and fill the new fields in place.

Comment: This is kind of a thing on the lines of conversions (between SAP upgrades). I am sure there a SAP solution for this. But want to do it myself. If am not wrong SPDD does something like this.

Comment: You are wrong. (Sorry to say it so bluntly, but what SPDD does is fundamentally different and not reusable in any way).

Comment: That is true. I only knew that SPDD was connected some way..but not sure what. That is the reason I am asking the question in the first place.